# Is Angularjs Clientside or Serverside or Both

Tags: php, node.js, angularjs

If server side: how can we connect to the database?

I was using it in client side, but can it also be used server side?

If it cannot be used server side should I use php or nodejs (I need to design a website which has a huge data bandwidth)?

Comment: AngularJS is a client-side JavaScript framework - use it with whatever you feel more comfortable with on the server.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is purely client side.

> If server side how can we connect to databases.

You either use a client side database or you get the data from the server using an appropriate protocol (typically this would be a web service accessed via Ajax).

> if not used in server side which one is better php or nodejs..( i need to design a website which uses huge data and bandwidth..)

"Better" without lots of measurable requirements is highly subjective.

Answer (score 10):

[Angular JS](http://angularjs.org) is a client side JavaScript framework for data binding. etc..

You can use [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/) for your server side operations along with Angular JS.

or Any other server side languages like PHP, Java, Etc...

Comment: Note, for the OP, the 'data-binding' in question here is binding the value of client-side data in JavaScript/JSON (the model) to placeholders in the templates (the view), not binding client-side interaction with back-end data. The use of the term 'data-binding' seems to be the cause for confusion as to whether Angular is client-side or server-side.

Comment: You can choose Spring-Boot or Spring-Cloud too for your server-side, it helps securing big-data access like to mongoDb

Answer (score 4):

Angular JS only works on the client-side. From my experience, I have found that it works best wih NodeJS (and in particular the ExpressJS framework) but any other server-side language could do.

AFAIK NodeJs makes it easier to manage big data.